Segment anything 2 FpnNeck can't find attribute d_model
I am encountering an AttributeError while working with the SAM2 model in a Jupyter notebook. I have installed the necessary packages: PyTorch, NumPy, and OpenCV.
{
    "name": "InstantiationException",
    "message": "Error in call to target 'sam2.modeling.sam2_base.SAM2Base':
AttributeError(\"'FpnNeck' object has no attribute 'd_model'\")
full_key: model",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\hydra\\_internal\\instantiate\\_instantiate2.py:92, in _call_target(_target_, _partial_, args, kwargs, full_key)
     91 try:
---> 92     return _target_(*args, **kwargs)
     93 except Exception as e:

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\sam2\\modeling\\sam2_base.py:121, in SAM2Base.__init__(self, image_encoder, memory_attention, memory_encoder, num_maskmem, image_size, backbone_stride, sigmoid_scale_for_mem_enc, sigmoid_bias_for_mem_enc, binarize_mask_from_pts_for_mem_enc, use_mask_input_as_output_without_sam, max_cond_frames_in_attn, directly_add_no_mem_embed, use_high_res_features_in_sam, multimask_output_in_sam, multimask_min_pt_num, multimask_max_pt_num, multimask_output_for_tracking, use_multimask_token_for_obj_ptr, iou_prediction_use_sigmoid, memory_temporal_stride_for_eval, non_overlap_masks_for_mem_enc, use_obj_ptrs_in_encoder, max_obj_ptrs_in_encoder, add_tpos_enc_to_obj_ptrs, proj_tpos_enc_in_obj_ptrs, use_signed_tpos_enc_to_obj_ptrs, only_obj_ptrs_in_the_past_for_eval, pred_obj_scores, pred_obj_scores_mlp, fixed_no_obj_ptr, soft_no_obj_ptr, use_mlp_for_obj_ptr_proj, no_obj_embed_spatial, sam_mask_decoder_extra_args, compile_image_encoder)
    120 self.memory_attention = memory_attention
--> 121 self.hidden_dim = image_encoder.neck.d_model
    123 # Part 3: memory encoder for the previous frame's outputs

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\torch\
n\\modules\\module.py:1729, in Module.__getattr__(self, name)
   1728         return modules[name]
-> 1729 raise AttributeError(f\"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'\")

AttributeError: 'FpnNeck' object has no attribute 'd_model'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InstantiationException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 7
      5 sam2_checkpoint = r\"C:\\Users\\AffixEngineering243\\Lucas\\sam2.1_hiera_large.pt\"
      6 model_cfg = r\"C:\\Users\\AffixEngineering243\\Lucas\\sam2_configs\\sam2_hiera_l - Copy.yaml\"
----> 7 sam2_model = build_sam2(model_cfg, sam2_checkpoint, device=device)
      9 predictor = SAM2ImagePredictor(sam2_model)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\sam2\\build_sam.py:36, in build_sam2(config_file, ckpt_path, device, mode, hydra_overrides_extra, apply_postprocessing, **kwargs)
     34 cfg = compose(config_name=config_file, overrides=hydra_overrides_extra)
     35 OmegaConf.resolve(cfg)
---> 36 model = instantiate(cfg.model, _recursive_=True)
     37 _load_checkpoint(model, ckpt_path)
     38 model = model.to(device)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\hydra\\_internal\\instantiate\\_instantiate2.py:226, in instantiate(config, *args, **kwargs)
    223     _convert_ = config.pop(_Keys.CONVERT, ConvertMode.NONE)
    224     _partial_ = config.pop(_Keys.PARTIAL, False)
--> 226     return instantiate_node(
    227         config, *args, recursive=_recursive_, convert=_convert_, partial=_partial_
    228     )
    229 elif OmegaConf.is_list(config):
    230     # Finalize config (convert targets to strings, merge with kwargs)
    231     config_copy = copy.deepcopy(config)

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\hydra\\_internal\\instantiate\\_instantiate2.py:347, in instantiate_node(node, convert, recursive, partial, *args)
    342                 value = instantiate_node(
    343                     value, convert=convert, recursive=recursive
    344                 )
    345             kwargs[key] = _convert_node(value, convert)
--> 347     return _call_target(_target_, partial, args, kwargs, full_key)
    348 else:
    349     # If ALL or PARTIAL non structured or OBJECT non structured,
    350     # instantiate in dict and resolve interpolations eagerly.
    351     if convert == ConvertMode.ALL or (
    352         convert in (ConvertMode.PARTIAL, ConvertMode.OBJECT)
    353         and node._metadata.object_type in (None, dict)
    354     ):

File ~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\hydra\\_internal\\instantiate\\_instantiate2.py:97, in _call_target(_target_, _partial_, args, kwargs, full_key)
     95 if full_key:
     96     msg += f\"\
full_key: {full_key}\"
---> 97 raise InstantiationException(msg) from e

InstantiationException: Error in call to target 'sam2.modeling.sam2_base.SAM2Base':
AttributeError(\"'FpnNeck' object has no attribute 'd_model'\")
full_key: model"
}

This is the code of my SAM2 testing:
import os
# if using Apple MPS, fall back to CPU for unsupported ops
os.environ["PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK"] = "1"
import numpy as np
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
elif torch.backends.mps.is_available():
    device = torch.device("mps")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
print(f"using device: {device}")

if device.type == "cuda":
    # use bfloat16 for the entire notebook
    torch.autocast("cuda", dtype=torch.bfloat16).__enter__()
    # turn on tfloat32 for Ampere GPUs (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#tensorfloat-32-tf32-on-ampere-devices)
    if torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).major >= 8:
        torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True
        torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32 = True
elif device.type == "mps":
    print(
        "\nSupport for MPS devices is preliminary. SAM 2 is trained with CUDA and might "
        "give numerically different outputs and sometimes degraded performance on MPS. "
        "See e.g. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/84936 for a discussion."
    )

from sam2.build_sam import build_sam2
from sam2.sam2_image_predictor import SAM2ImagePredictor


sam2_checkpoint = r"C:\Users\AffixEngineering243\Lucas\sam2.1_hiera_large.pt"
model_cfg = r"C:\Users\AffixEngineering243\Lucas\sam2_configs\sam2_hiera_l - Copy.yaml"
sam2_model = build_sam2(model_cfg, sam2_checkpoint, device=device)

predictor = SAM2ImagePredictor(sam2_model)

I used copy because the original yaml was outdated.
Relevant Code Snippet, Here is the relevant part of my YAML configuration file:
arget: sam2.modeling.sam2_base.SAM2Baseimage_encoder:target: sam2.modeling.backbones.image_encoder.ImageEncoderscalp: 1trunk:target: sam2.modeling.backbones.hieradet.Hieraembed_dim: 144num_heads: 2stages: [2, 6, 36, 4]global_att_blocks: [23, 33, 43]window_pos_embed_bkg_spatial_size: [7, 7]window_spec: [8, 4, 16, 8]neck:target: sam2.modeling.backbones.image_encoder.FpnNeckposition_encoding:target: sam2.modeling.position_encoding.PositionEmbeddingSinenum_pos_feats: 256normalize: truescale: nulltemperature: 10000d_model: 256backbone_channel_list: [1152, 576, 288, 144]fpn_top_down_levels: [2, 3]fpn_interp_model: nearestIn the sam2_base.py file, 

I found the following line which causes the error:
 self.hidden_dim = image_encoder.neck.d_mode

Why am I receiving this error indicating that the FpnNeck object has no attribute d_model?
How can I resolve this issue to ensure that d_model is properly accessed?

Where exactly? Please edit your post to include the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].
